# How to Uninstall Fake uBlock

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, adblock, ublock

I'm working as tech support in a High School which exclusively uses Windows devices (Surface Pro), and we often see students come in with uBlock installed in their browser, typically in Edge.

Our network is pretty locked down and anything that messes around with network settings, like VPN's or some ad-blockers, can cause the students to not be able to operate on the local network.

uBlock seems to be a big offender (it seems "uBlock Origin" is the legit version, and "uBlock Pro" is the bad version), but I haven't found a way to uninstall it. I have seen some articles (https://www.tomshardware.com/news/adblock-ublock-fake-google-chrome-browser-extensions,40422.html) claiming there is a fake version of uBlock floating around, but the articles are old. There are other posts on Reddit which I'd link to, but I'm posting this from work and Redit is blocked.

I just installed uBlock from the MS Edge Add-ons site (https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ublock-origin/odfafepnkmbhccpbejgmiehpchacaeak) and it seems to be benign. I can disable it, and even remove it without a problem. But the version I'm seeing on student computers has the disable button greyed out, and there is no option to remove it in the extension manager. I think I could get rid of it by playing around in the registry, but that's a last resort.

Has anyone come across this "fake" uBlock?

And does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Delete the Edge user profile.

Comment: Is removal a user-dependent issue? Work with one student to have her or him log in and try to remove uBlock. Also, if it *is* malware, ask how it was put on the machine, and send a  notice to warn others.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The students all claim they don't know how it got there.
Somebody else sent me a link to this article for removing it... https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-ublock-pro/

Comment: @Snuffleupagus, It might be worth writing up a summary on removing it: that's a useful answer to a question others might have! +1